# Update column value Array[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that contains many columns and I convert it in `Array[Row]`
using collect:

```
var table = df.collect()
```

after this, I try to loop into it and modify a value of certain columns

```
  for(i <- 0 to dfEleve.length-1){
        var value = dfEleve.apply(i).getAs("uid")
  }
```

I search how to update a value of a column.

Input :

```
|Name  | age | uid |
--------------------   
|David | 25  |     |
|Jean  | 20  |     |
```

Output

```
|Name  | age | uid       |
--------------------------  
|David | 25  |   uip154  |
|Jean  | 20  |   uaz214  |
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly : you want to update/modify certain columns of your dataframe, then I suggest you to use `udf` function and call the `udf` function with `withColumn` function. 
for example:
for the input and output in your question:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = Seq(("David", 25, ""), ("Jean", 20, "")).toDF("Name", "age", "uid")
df.withColumn("uid", testUdf(df("Name")))


import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def testUdf = udf((value: String) => {
    if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("David")) "uip154"
    else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("Jean")) "uaz214"
    else ""
  })
```

you can edit the testUdf funtion to meet your logic